# Spring properties file -Conditional Properties true/false

Tags: spring

I have a properties file with a boolean key say trueFlag.

## dev.properties

trueflag=true

I want it to be used in my application context in two places

```
    <property name="autoStartup" value="${trueflag}"></property>
```

and another

**Note: the negation**

```
    <property name="autoStartup" value="!${trueflag}"></property>
```

Is this possible? How can I achieve this. Code snippets will be helpful as I am new to Spring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally resolved from the previous hint,

One can give it this way

```
    <property name="autoStartup" value="#{!${trueflag}}"></property>
```

Thanks stivlo.

Answer (score 0):

The `${...}` syntax only represents a placeholder. It's not an EL syntax. For that, you'd want to look into [Spring EL](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try this `#{!${trueflag}}` using the SpEL